# How to target iPad and iPhone, but exclude Android

Tags: android, iphone, css, ipad, meta-tags

I've been searching for this answer, but I can't seem to find it. I only have an iPhone and iPad - I don't have an Android - so I don't know if my CSS is even touching the Droid?

This is what I have in my HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
... CSS for iPad landscape
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
... CSS for iPad portrait
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
... CSS for iPhone portrait and landscape
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a specific meta tag for the Droid?
2. Does the CSS I have above address the Droid? If so, is there a way it can be modified so that the Droid ignores it?
3. Is there an online emulator for the Droid so I can troubleshoot?

You can see a sample page here: http://www2.receivablesxchange.com/alternative-to-factoring-4

Comment: Also, if this has been answered elsewhere, please point me to it. I've already done at least 1/2 hour of research and I'm running out of time. I'm not quite sure how to formulate search query to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Media queries are for display area and type. It doesn't look at the user agent or anything like that. What you could do is something like this with JQuery + CSS:

```
var _device = {};

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    _device.name = 'ipad';
    _device.type = 'mobile';
} else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
    _device.name = 'android';
    _device.type = 'mobile';
} else {
    _device.type = 'desktop';
}

$('body').addClass(_device.name).addClass(_device.type);
```

Now, in your CSS, you simply prepend the body class which applies to your needs:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) { 
    .ipad #myDiv {
        // css for #myDiv only seen on the iPad
    }

    .android #myDiv {
        // css for #myDiv only seen on the Android
    }

    .mobile #myDiv {
        // css for #myDiv available to iPad AND android but NOT desktop
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this media query target the ipad specifically? @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
... CSS for iPad landscape
}

Comment: And if the answer is a combo of JS and CSS, that's fine as well. But it was my understanding that the addition of orientation in combination with the min/max device width was a way to target that specific device?

Comment: It isn't future proof, what if an android device has the same screen width?

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor The media query will target any device with that display - in theory and in practice, you could resize your desktop browser to that exact aspect ratio and watch your css pop into that media query conditional.

Comment: That's how I've been testing, however, in order for it to work on the desktop the query must be "min-width" NOT "min-device-width". To test I just remove device and look at it in the browser. I was mostly curious about whether there are any specific parameters I could pass that would make the query Android specific? For example, I can target an iPhone 4 by using "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio" and "min-device-pixel-ratio" together. Anyway, thanks for your help. I may have found the answers I need here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: If you really care about pixel perfection on multiple devices, you can check out [Adobe Shadow](http://success.adobe.com/en/na/sem/products/shadow.html) or if you really have coin to spare, check out [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/index.aspx) which lets you remote into any of over 1000 devices at their server center.